# Active record query to get the records that have 0 nested associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to write an active record query which will return all the author_ids that have 0 comments on all of their posts.

```rb
class Author
  has_many :posts
end

class Post
  has_many :comments
  belongs_to :author
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I came up with looping the authors but I know it is not a good practice and want to find a way to write it in one query.

```
ids = []

Authors.joins(:posts).each do |author|
  has_zero_comments = true

  author.posts.joins(:comments).each do |post|
    if post.comments.any?
      has_zero_comments = false
      break
    end
  end

  ids << author.id if has_zero_comments
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to get all of the posts that don't have comments, then join that to the Authors.

```
## This gets all the posts with no comments
posts = Post.includes(:comments).where(comments: { post_id: nil });

## This gets all the accounts with posts with no comments
accounts = Account.joins(:posts).merge(posts)
```

Does that work for you? This will actually end up being one db request also.

Answer (score 0):

You can get author ids with this code:

```
Author.joins(posts: :comments).where(posts: {comment: nil}).ids
```

Comment: Might have to use `left_outer_joins(posts: :comments)` instead of `joins` (which is inner join)

Comment: [`ids`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-ids) is enough to get each model record id.

Comment: @stepan if I use left_outer_joins, there will be authors without posts.